# How I can positionning my Image in such a way that the Image dont exceed my with screen?

Tags: css

[image: My probleme]

Here what I have when I use this css code :

```
  .circleImage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    left: 300px;
    top: 570px;
  }
```

And the result that I wish is here :

[image: The result]

I try fixed and sticky in postion type, i dont exceed my screen but fixed or sticky does not correspond with my result

Thanks for the people who take time to help me

Comment: add overflow:hidden on image parent

Answer (score 0):

Just use responsive units to position the image.

```css
.circleImage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    left: 30%;
    top: 30vh;
  }
```

```html
<img class="circleImage" src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/b/390-3904056_round-profile-round-profile-clipart.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using fixed value like `300px` which pushed the image outside the parent because the parent width is not that much wider. So use `%` like the answer above.

If you want to center it:

You can use this method to center any child with sticky/fixed/absolute container. Set the `left` and `right` value to `0`. Then add `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`. This will center the child regardless the parent width.

```css
.circleImage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRn0sYfGooUSN-KGwa4xg2JbzdSB_wCC6_aA&usqp=CAU" class="circleImage">
```

Comment: Yes thanks I try this, but when i add 65% in left is exceed the width parent